# C# extract .zip file downloaded from server sided

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hello I have to extract a `.zip` that my program is downloading from a server in the same route that is downloaded.

The code I'm using is

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
{
     foreach (ZipEntry zipFiles in zip)
     {
         zipFiles.Extract(Root + "\\Resource\\", true);
     }
}
```

But I cannot make the program auto-extract it. I'm using `Ionic.Zip`

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: There's no error. Program compiles well, but it does not extract the file that is downloading

Comment: @MineR There's no error. Program compiles well, but it does not extract the file that is downloading

Comment: can you please provide [mcve]

Comment: check your outputDirectory Path ( for correct and exist )

Comment: Check My answer...

Comment: ZipFile ? What library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct however you can use from this method

for extract all :

```
public void ExtractFileToDirectory(string zipFileName, string outputDirectory)
{
     ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileName);
     Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);
     zip.ExtractAll(outputDirectory,ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```

for extract one by one :

```
public void ExtractFileToDirectory(string zipFileName, string outputDirectory)
{
     ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileName);
     Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);
      foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
      {
          e.Extract(outputDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
      }
}
```

so checkeck your `outputDirectory` that should be correct and exist

Sample Usage :

```
    string current_directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    string Extract_dir_name = "Extract";
    string OutoutputDirectory = current_directory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Extract_dir_name;
    if (check_dir(OutoutputDirectory))
    {
        if (File.Exists(zip_file_loc))
        {
            ExtractFileToDirectory(zip_file_loc, OutoutputDirectory);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File Is Not Exists");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Dir Is Not Exists");
    }
```

And Method for check Dir :

```
    private bool check_dir(string outputDirectory)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(outputDirectory))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```